How can I display a PDF in-app using the AndroidX PdfViewer?
How to load or display a PDF within my app instead of using an external app by using an Uri? I want to use the official androidx,pdfviewer library.
My app-level build.gradle looks like this:
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.pdfviewer:pdfviewer:1.0.0-alpha04")
}

This is my PDFViewer Composable:
@Composable
fun PdfViewer(uri: Uri) {
   AndroidView(
       factory = { context ->
           PDFView(context).apply {
               fromUri(uri).defaultPage(0) // Set default page to 0
               this.load() // Call load() on the PDFView instance
           }
       },
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
   )
}

However, I am getting this error:

Unresolved reference PDFView


Here is my complete project for reading PDF file using Jetpack compose : https://github.com/chiragthummar/PDFReaderJetpackCompose.git

I added an answer below. If it resolves your issue, please consider marking it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark button at the left side of the answer. Thank you!

The androidx.pdfviewer:pdfviewer does not offer any View that you can use. Instead, it offers a Fragment called PdfViewerFragment.
To display the PdfViewerFragment in Compose, you will need the following dependencies:
implementation("androidx.pdf:pdf-viewer-fragment:1.0.0-alpha04")
implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-compose:1.8.5")

Next, the application style defined in your theme.xml must extend any Material3 theme:
<style name="Theme.ComposePlayground" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar" />

Finally, you can use the AndroidFragment Composable to display the PdfViewerFragment:
@Composable
fun PdfViewer(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, uri: Uri) {
    AndroidFragment<PdfViewerFragment>(
        arguments = bundleOf("documentUri" to uri),
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

The PdfViewerFragment takes the Uri from the Fragment arguments Bundle passed with key "documentUri". Note that currently, only Uris starting with

content://
file://

are supported, so you can't open online PDFs.
Example:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DocumentViewer() {
    var documentUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) {
        documentUri = it
    }

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
            title = { Text("Document Viewer") }
        )
        FilledTonalButton(
            onClick = {
                launcher.launch(arrayOf("application/pdf"))
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Select Document")
        }
        documentUri?.let {
            PdfViewer(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).fillMaxWidth(),
                uri = it
            )
        }
    }
}

Output:

Note:
The PdfViewerFragment still is in early development and might have bugs. Also, there are many limitations on the API levels where you can use it. I tested it on API35, but if you want to use it with an older minSdk, you might need to use SDK Extensions. The linter will tell you if you need to use them.
